# function hideTab() not working in shinydashboard for individual dynamic tabs

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am creating dynamic tabs based on clicks on a datatable with an action button on each newly created tab which when clicked, hides this tab. The new tabs are getting created as expected, but the hide action button does not work when I open more than one tab. Is there something I am missing?

```
    library(shiny)
    library(DT)
    library(shinydashboard)

    ui <- function(request) {
        dashboardPage(
            dashboardHeader(title = "Tabs not Hiding"),
            dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
            dashboardBody(
                tabBox(id = "tabs",
                    width = 12, 
                    tabPanel("Cars overview",
                                h1("Cars overview"),
                                div("Click any cell"),
                                br(),
                                DT::dataTableOutput("mtcars")
                            )
                )
            )
        )
    }

    server <- function(input, output, session) {

        tab_list <- NULL

        # Generate data table
        output$mtcars <- DT::renderDataTable({
            DT::datatable(mtcars)
            })

        observeEvent(input$mtcars_cell_clicked, {

            info <- as.numeric(input$mtcars_cell_clicked$row)

            outputID <- glue::glue("dt-{info}")

            req(info)

            if(!(info %in% tab_list)){
                print(info)
                appendTab(inputId = "tabs",
                        tabPanel(title = outputID,
                                fluidRow(
                                    box(
                                        actionButton("TabHide", "Hide this tab"),
                                        width = 3
                                    ),
                                    box(
                                        DT::dataTableOutput(outputID),
                                        width = 9
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                        )
                tab_list <<- c(tab_list, outputID)
            }

            output[[outputID]] <- DT::renderDataTable({
                mtcars[info, ]
            })

            showTab(inputId = "tabs", target = outputID, select = TRUE)

            observeEvent(input$TabHide,{
                hideTab(input = "tabs", target = outputID)
            }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this version of server function, I add comments to changes what I did:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  tab_list <- NULL

  # Generate data table
  output$mtcars <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(mtcars)
  })

  # Add proxy object to manipulate DT
  dtProxy <- dataTableProxy('mtcars')

  observeEvent(input$mtcars_rows_selected, {

    info <- as.numeric(input$mtcars_row_last_clicked)

    # Clear DT selection via proxy
    selectRows(dtProxy, NULL)

    outputID <- glue::glue("dt-{info}")

    req(info)

    # Check for 'outputID' in tab_list instead of 'info' variable (missprint?)
    if(!(outputID %in% tab_list)){
      appendTab(inputId = "tabs",
                tabPanel(title = outputID,
                         fluidRow(
                           box(
                             # Create buttons with unique inputId
                             actionButton(paste0("TabHide", outputID), "Hide this tab"),
                             width = 3
                           ),
                           box(
                             DT::dataTableOutput(outputID),
                             width = 9
                           )
                         )
                )
      )
      tab_list <<- c(tab_list, outputID)
    }

    output[[outputID]] <- DT::renderDataTable({
      mtcars[info, ]
    })

    showTab(inputId = "tabs", target = outputID, select = TRUE)

    # Add observer for actionButton from opened tab (part 'input[["some_inputId"]]')
    observeEvent(input[[paste0("TabHide", outputID)]],{
      # Use 'removeTab' instead of 'hideTab', be cause of tab duplicates
      removeTab(input = "tabs", target = outputID)
      # Remove tab from 'tab_list', as we know this observer will delete tab from page
      tab_list <<- tab_list[!tab_list %in% outputID]
      # Add 'once = TRUE' to destroy observer after tab closed (we will create new observer again when open tab)
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE, once = TRUE)
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
}
```

**Overall**: just attention to details.